# Python regex named groups in special formated string

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

**Objective:**

1. I have input string where it is separated by commas and key values in between
2. I want to write regex with names groups so i can extract and replace values of each property

in string `*keyword , property1 = ABC,  property2 = 2` I want to find and replace value of `property1` and `property2` by name

for given string `*keyword , property1 = ABC,  property2 = 2` , result string should be `*keyword , property1 = DEF,  property2 = 10`

See code below

```py
import re

# find property1 in given string and replace its new value
property1 = 'DEF'
# find property2 in given string and replace its new value
property2 = '10'

line1 = '*keyword , property1 = ABC,  property2 = 2 '
line2 = '*keyword , property2 = 2,  property1 = ABC ' #property2 comes before proeprty1
line3 = '*keyword,property1=ABC,property2= 2' #same as line 1 but without spaces

regex_with_named_group = r'=\s*(.*)\s*,\s*property1=\s*(.*)\s*,'

line1_found = re.search(regex_with_named_group, line1)
line2_found = re.search(regex_with_named_group, line2)
line3_found = re.search(regex_with_named_group, line3)

if line1_found:
    print( line1_found.group('property1'), line1_found.group('property2') )

if line2_found:
    print( line2_found.group('property1'), line2_found.group('property2') )

if line3_found:
    print(line3_found.group('property1'), line3_found.group('property2'))
```

Comment: what output format  you want

Comment: I want to replace value of ```property1``` which is ```ABC``` by any for sake of example by fetching it with named group

Comment: Unless I'm missing something it seems like your regex doesnt have a named capture group which can be created using this construct: `(?P<name>...)
`

Comment: @SitiSchu yes, I am not familair with named group syntax and need advise here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goals, I suggest considering using the [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

```py
import re

line0 = '*keyword , fruit=apple, juice= mango'
line1 = '*keyword , property1 = ABC,  property2 = 2 '
line2 = '*keyword , property2 = 2,  property1 = ABC ' #property2 comes before proeprty1
line3 = '*keyword,property1=ABC,property2= 2' #same as line 1 but without spaces

regex_with_named_group = re.compile(r'(?P<prop>\w+)(?P<map>\s*=\s*)(?P<val>\w+)')
repl = {'fruit':'avocado', 'property1':170}
for l in [line0, line1, line2, line3]:
    s = regex_with_named_group.sub(lambda m: m.group('prop') + m.group('map') +
                                             (str(repl[m.group('prop')])
                                              if m.group('prop') in repl
                                              else m.group('val')), l)
    print(s)
```

Result:

```
*keyword , fruit=avocado, juice= mango
*keyword , property1 = 170,  property2 = 2 
*keyword , property2 = 2,  property1 = 170 
*keyword,property1=170,property2= 2
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/KQMY88308).

Comment: thankx, very helpful, but for sake of example i simplified and write proeprty1 and proeprty2. They can be actually anything like ```*keyword , fruit=apple, juice= mango```

Comment: thankx. what i wanted !!! BTW how do i repalce new value in string ? for example find value of fruit and and change it

Comment: I rewrote my code a bit to bring it into line with your requirements. But I still do not understand what to do with the "* keyword" part.

Comment: how can i replace value of each property ?

Comment: It's easy like `d['fruit'] = 'avocado'`.

Comment: No i mean captured replacement for example output becomes ```line0 = '*keyword , fruit=avocado, juice= mango'```

Comment: I think I got what you need :) Look at my updated answer.